# How to not multiply space in multiplication & mod?

Tags: python

I've successfully made a function that takes a string and an int and returns a new string derived from the argument string but with some characters repeated/removed. Each character is multipled by its ord mod x. I'm unsure how I can prevent it from doing it to blank spaces though.

Here is the entire chunk of code including the doctest:

```
def balloon_string(string, x):
    """
    >>> balloon_string('abcdef', 4)
    'abbccceff'
    >>> balloon_string('A great day!', 4)
    'Agggrreaay!'
    >>> balloon_string('ABC 1234', 3)
    'AAC 1224'
    """
    l = []
    for ch in string:
        l.append(str(ch*(ord(ch)%x)))
    return ''.join(l)
```

The output I get from this is:

```
Expecting:
    'abbccceff'
ok

Expecting:
    'Agggrreaay!'
ok

Expected:
    'AAC 1224'
Got:
    'AAC  1224'
```

As you can see, the last one has an extra space and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: check if `ch` is a space, and don't do the doubling thing if it is:

```
if ch == ' ' and ord(ch)%x != 0:
    l.append(ch)
else:
    l.append(ch*(ord(ch)%x))  # since ch is already a str, casting this back to str is unnecessary
```

Alternatively, you can do a cool one-liner:

```
l.append(ch*(ord(ch)%x) if (ch != ' ' or ord(ch) % x == 0) else ch)
```

Comment: I've updated my answer - you'd just want to add a second clause to the conditional, to check whether `ord(ch) % x` is equal to 0, in which case do the original thing instead. That should address your test case, though it's a bit less elegant

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in one line like this:

```
def balloon_string(string, x):
    return ''.join((c * (ord(c) % x)) if c != ' ' else c for c in string)

print(balloon_string('abcdef', 4))
# abbccceff
print(balloon_string('A great day!', 4))
# A gggrrea ay!
print(balloon_string('ABC 1234', 3))
# AAC 1224
```